# How can i run my python code file every day on multiple times, which i'm taking from csv, I want to run a python code file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scheduled-tasks

I have a csv file in that file multiple times are stored -

```
09:00:50
11:34:59
12:45:34
12:56:35
15:12:39
```

etc.
And I want to run my python code file every day at these times,
Here I'm talking about a file not code.
but I don't understand how can I do this?
my python file name is - practice.ipynb

I want to run my file by using a code, except the window task scheduler.
please help me to solve this problem.

I was using this code but it's not working as I want.

```
import schedule
import time
import pandas as pd

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

times = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\krishna gupta\py_venv\My_Programming\Trade_global\My Codes\Automate_login\times_input.csv")
for i in range(len(times)):
    timing = times.iloc[i][0]
    print(timing)
    schedule.every().day.at(timing).do(job)
    
        
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: How is this working? Maybe you should add the day in your csv file

Comment: Better to manage it on OS level. Any modern OS has some kind of task scheduler, so you can use it. In Linux it's [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), in Windows it's [task scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page).

Comment: @OrangoMango sorry i don't understand what are you saying.

Comment: @OlvinRoght how ?

Comment: @KrishnaGupta You said its not working as you want, what's the code doing?

Comment: @OrangoMango it's work for one time and then its stuck in loop, and it not reach next time. example - first i wna to run this on 09:30 an then 10:00 . so it's run 09:30 but not run 10:00. its stuck in 09:30 loop

Comment: Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run file with the following syntax `subprocess.call(['python', 'somescript.py', somescript_arg1, somescript_val1,...]).`

Comment: @KrishnaGupta I think that your program is running a csv line every day. You should change the code so that runs the function in the same day

Comment: @KrishnaGupta, create python script which does job once and set up OS task with required schedule.

Comment: Why you can't use crontab .?

Comment: @badhushamuhammed crontab is a software, right? but i wan to use code.

Comment: @KrishnaGupta if you want to run your file multiple times, write some code to loop indefinitely and call your script at the scheduled times.  Have you tried that?  This will be a less reliable version of the built-in OS task scheduling functionality..

Comment: @JeffUK I don't understand, how? Listen I'm a beginner in programming, can you please help me through code?